# SalesForce Custom Object Delete Records

Tags: apex, sales-cloud

How can I delete all records from a custom object

Comment: There is no truncate option on the object I followed the instructions to add truncate but it still does not show

Comment: Not all objects can be truncated, did you check the [Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_object_trunc_overview.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 0):

See [Truncate Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_object_trunc.htm&type=5).

Go to the detail page for the custom object, and click the Truncate button.

Comment: There is no truncate button

Comment: @PinkstonMatt Please read [Considerations for Truncating Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_object_trunc_overview.htm&type=5). Certain conditions may make truncation impossible. It is apparently only in Classic, as well. See if you can switch to the Classic theme.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted manually, with no proper solution provided